# @Before annotation in mailers notifier

Tags: java, playframework, mailer

How can I use correctly @Before annotation in Mailer notifier?
I have tried to use @Before annotation in Mailer notifier :

```
public class Mails extends Mailer {

    @Before
    public static void testAnnotation(){
        System.out.println("TEST");
    }

    .....
}
```

But it's not working, if this approach is wrong please let me know how can I execute my specific method in Mailer notifier before executing any other methods. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to execute one specific method ( for checking purpose ) before starting to execute Mailer. Or precisely, want to check is there email address of the particular user before sending any email.

Comment: Is the @Before annotation coming from junit? If so, that is not it is supposed to be used. It is a junit annotation used to execute a setup before the test method executes. It can't be used in production code.

Comment: No it's not from junit, it's from Playframework.

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: I am using version 1.3.x

Comment: Is `Mails` a controller? If I remember correctly, `@Before` just works for controllers.

Comment: Mails is a notifier, not controller :( it means I cannot use @Before in notifier?

Comment: It can't. `@Before` is a feature related to controllers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what can I use then instead of @Before in notifier, I mean alternatives of @Before?